# How to set specific marker show on another markers in markers list use Angular Google maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps

I'm using [Angular Google Maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps), an I have some markers in map:

```
$scope.markers = [
  {
    id: 5,
    latitude: 44.4284821,
    longitude: 26.1241451,
    icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue.png'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    latitude: 43,
    longitude: 26.1241451
  }

];
```

This is my example: [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YhjCJoiHxjFd8hZbcP0j?p=preview)

I would like set specific `z-index` to marker blue (id is 5) always show on marker icon red (id is 4) or other markers. And don't care about `lat`, `long` of it. If can't use `z-index`, please give me another ways.

***Note: Index of marker blue always is 0 in markers array***.

Hope you help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control z-order for marker objects ([`google.maps.Marker`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerOptions)) two properties needs to be specified:

```
z-index: <value>
optimized:false
```

In case of [angular-google-maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps) library you could set `z-index` & `optimized` properties as shown below:

```
<ui-gmap-markers models="markers" options="'options'" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" zIndex="'zIndex'" optimized="'optimized'">
</ui-gmap-markers>

$scope.markers = [
  {
    id: 5,
    latitude: 44.4284821,
    longitude: 26.1241451,
    icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue.png',
    options : {
       zIndex: 923,
       optimized: false
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    latitude: 43,
    longitude: 26.1241451,
    options : {
       zIndex: 611,
       optimized: false
    }   
  }

];
```

**Example**

```js
angular.module('appMaps', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.markers = [
      {
        id: 5,
        latitude: 44.4284821,
        longitude: 26.1241451,
        icon: 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue.png',
        options : {
           zIndex: 923,
           optimized: false
        }
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        latitude: 43,
        longitude: 26.1241451,
        options : {
           zIndex: 611,
           optimized: false
        }   
      }

    ];

    $scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: 32,
        longitude: 15
      },
      zoom: 4,
      bounds: {},
      markers: {
        models: [],
        type: 'cluster',
        typeOptions: {
          minimumClusterSize: 12,
          gridSize: 60
        }
      },
      options: {
        mapTypeControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true
      }
    };

  });
```

```css
 html, body, #map_canvas {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #map_canvas {
            position: relative;
        }

        .angular-google-map-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" ng-app="appMaps" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="map.options" bounds="map.bounds">
        <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" options="'options'" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" zIndex="'zIndex'" optimized="'optimized'">
        </ui-gmap-markers>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

[Modified plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O7P5plmyIDXkNx13a395?p=preview)

Comment: I tried with `zIndex` and `optimized` in `options` property, but I missed set `options="'options'"` in view. Thanks for good answer

Answer (score 0):

we can't sent z-index of markers because google-maps is making a canvass and then getting rendered.
So if you deliberately want to change z-index, you must have to change the marker images accordingly, because once the google map is rendered, we can't change the z-index.

Comment: Which another way without `z-index`?

Comment: you can use different images of different shades for different markers, and give z-index only to text embedded on top of each marker, as google-maps create a canvass for markers not the text on top of it. But this will be a very haphazard way of doing.

Comment: "options": {
         "labelContent": markerText                  
     }, 
     "icon": imagePath

This is how we can manually specify each marker with required image and text on it.
Check google-maps implementation for reference

Comment: It can't make a specific marker always show on another markers.